# Seeking an LLM with Browser Control Capabilities for Website Interaction Use Cases

Tags: language-model

I'm exploring the possibility of using a large language model (LLM) that can interact with web browsers, including taking screenshots and controlling mouse and keyboard actions.  Does anyone know of an LLM capable of such functionalities? Any guidance or pointers to relevant resources?